# change value of input box on form submit using serialize array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

hello I have a input text box with height option. When user inputs height in it I have to submit the form only after multiplying the value in the input box by 0.45 using serialise array option in jquery or anyother method if possible.

```
<input id="height"type="text"></input>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update value in input box before making serialize data of the form. Here's the code you can try:

```
$("#height").blur(function(){
    var inputValue = $(this).val();
    if(inputValue > 0){
       $(this).val(inputValue*0.45);
    }
});
```

Now you can serialize the form data as:

```
var serializedData = $("#formId").serialize();
```

And, simply submit it with your ajax.

Comment: can you please give me how will i serialize after changing the value

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this also

```
<input id="height"type="text" onblur='this.value = (this.value*0.45);'></input>
```

For serializing the data using jQuery use this

```
var tempData = $("#your-form-id").serialize();
```